# Finding perimeter of polygon inscribed in circle

Tags: circles, polygons

n equally spaced points are taken on the circumference of a circle of radius 1. How do you find the perimeter of the resulting regular polygon obtained by joining the n points in order?

Comment: Connect the vertices to the center. Now you have $n$ equal isosceles triangles. How do you find the lengths of their bases?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Partition the regular polygon in $n$ isosceles triangles with a common vertex at the centre of the circle. The altitude of such  a triangle is equal to $\cos\frac{\pi}n$. Can you find its base?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** $n \sqrt{2r^2 (1-\cos(2\pi/n))}$. This formula is equivalent to:

$$ 2nr \sin(\pi/n) $$

**Explanation:** Using the cosine rule: since we are given 2 sides and the opposite angle of the missing side, we obtain the last side with the following formula:
$$ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos(\theta)$$
$$ \implies \text{missing}^2 = 2r^2 - 2r^2 \cos(2\pi/n) $$

The equivalence to the second formula comes from the fact that
$$ \sqrt{2-2\cos(2x)} = 2\sin(x) $$

[[image: Problem image] width = 100px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bA8Z.png)

Honestly, I don't know why people on this website are unable to provide quick answers to easy problems. I had this same question, and even though it only took me like 5 minutes to derive the formula, this is the kind of stuff you would actually prefer a formula answer instead of a vague hint.

Answer (score 0):

Bisect one triangle of the polygon by a radial line. Angle at circle center is $ \dfrac {2\pi}{2n}. $

We see a right angled triangle of sides:

$$ ( 1, \cos \frac {\pi}{n},  \sin \frac {\pi}{n})$$

Directly the polygon perimeter is $$ 2 n \sin \frac {\pi}{n} $$

Give it a check:

$$\lim_{~~n\to \infty} 2 n \sin \dfrac {\pi}{n} = 2\pi$$